# Question on Linearised system

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have this question :

study the nature of the critical point for  the linearized system of : $x''+x'^3+x=0$

please how we find the linearised system of $x''+x'^3+x=0$.

Please help me ,

Thank you

Comment: Is that notation taking $(x')^3$ or does it mean something else?

Comment: yes it is the notation taking

Answer (score 3):

Given:

$$x''+(x')^3+x=0$$

We want to study the nature of the critical point for the linearized system.

We start off by writing this as a system of equations (they happen to be nonlinear) as follows. Let $x_1 = x$, so

- $x_1' = x' = x_2$
- $x_2' = x'' = -(x')^3 - x = -x_2^{3} - x_1$

So we can write this as a system:

- $x_1' = x_2$
- $x_2' = -x_1 -x_2^{3}$

The next steps:

- $(1)$ Find the critical points
- $(2)$ Linearize the system using those critical points
- $(3)$ Classify the linearization of those critical points
- $(4)$ Draw the phase portrait to validate or invalidate the above
- $(5)$ Analyze that result using the theory for correctness based on all of the above

Here are phase portraits, for example (the second one gets closer into the origin).

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is the the linearized system ?

Comment: the second equation should be $x_2'=−x_1−x_2^3$. Then, you have to find the roots of $f(x_1,x_2)=x_2$ and $g(x_1,x_2)=-x_1-x_2^3$, linearize around them and solve the underlying linear ode.

Comment: @Vrouvrou: What book are you using? Have you been able to progress? Do you know how to find the critical points? Do you know how you would go about classifying them?

Comment: Nice outline: the kind of thing one can add to one's notes for "now and later"...